# How does it possible to pass value from child job to parent on Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I know it possible to pass values from parent to child jobs using [Multijob Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin)

Is it possible to pass variables from child job to parent?

Comment: You already got the answer below. But I just wanted to mention that if you are building job pipelines which are anything more than two jobs, or if you are building several similar pipelines, then you will eventually want to migrate over to the workflow plugin instead.
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workflow+Plugin

Lots of pipelines of separately GUI-configured jobs passing parameters between each other using complicated workarounds... It becomes a unmaintainable mess really fast.
"Workflow" seems to be the future of Jenkins.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes with a little work. If JobParent calls jobChild and you want to have variableChild1 (that you may have created in jobChild job) to be visible in jobParent job then do the following simple steps.

1. In the child job, create a file (variable=value) pair with all the variables in it. Lets call it child or downstream_job or jobChild_envs.txt
2. Now, once jobParent is done calling jobChild (I guess you are calling Trigger another project or Build other project steps etc), next action just would be to use "Copy Artifact from another project/job" (Copy Artifact plugin in Jenkins). PS: You would need to click on the check box to FLATTEN the file (see jobParent image below). https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin

   Using this plugin, you'll be able to get a file/folder from jobChild's workspace into jobParent's workspace in a defined/base workspace location.
3. In jobParent, you'll Inject Environment variables (in the BUILD step).
   https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin

At this time, if jobChild job created a .txt file with a variable for ex:

```
variableChild1=valueChild1
```

in it, then it'll be available/visible to the parent/upstrem job jobParent.

See the images for more details and run the jobs at your end to see the output.

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Also the child job should "archive the artifacts"

Comment: Without archiving the artifacts the copyArtifact plugin wont work. Is there any way to not to archive the artifacts and then copy?

Answer (score 3):

In pipeline builds, you can do this as follows.  Let's say you want to save the child build's URL and pass it back to the parent pipeline.

In your child build...

```
// write out some data about the job
def jobData = [job_url: "${BUILD_URL}"]
def jobDataText = groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(jobData)
writeFile file: "jobDataChild.json", text: jobDataText, encoding: 'UTF-8'

// archive the artifacts
archiveArtifacts artifacts: "jobDataChild.json", onlyIfSuccessful: false
```

And you can retrieve this in the parent build...

```
step ([$class: 'CopyArtifact', projectName: 'ChildJobName', filter: "jobDataChild.json", selector: [$class: 'LastCompletedBuildSelector'] ])
if (fileExists("jobDataChild.json")) {
    def jobData = readJSON file: "jobDataChild.json"
    def jobUrl = jobData.job_url
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to this answer years later. The way i'm doing it is by having a redis instance that pipelines can connect to and pass data back and forth.

```
sh "redis-cli -u $redis_url ping" // server is up
def redis_key = "$BUILD_TAG" // BUILD_TAG is always unique

build job: "child", propagate: true, wait: true, parameters: [
    string(name: "redis", value: "$redis_url;$redis_key"),
]

/******** in child job ***********/
def (redis_url, redis_key) = env.redis.tokenize(";")
sh"redis-cli -u $redis_url ping"  // we are connected on url

// lpush adds to an array in redis
sh"""
    redis-cli -u $redis_url lpush $redis_key "MY_DATA"
"""  

/******* in parent job after waiting for child job *****/
def data_from_child = sh(script: "redis-cli --raw -u $redis_url LRANGE $redis_key 0 -1", returnStdout: true)

data_from_child == "MY_DATA"? println("") : error("wow did not expect this")
```

I kind of like this approach better than passing back and forth with files because it allows scaling up via multiple worker nodes and executing multiple jobs in parallel.